# stream filter return null findFirst getting exception

Tags: java, java-stream, filtering

The following will throw an exception, if the `personList` is empty or the filtered result is empty:

```
Person b2cInwardAllocTxs = personList.stream()
   .filter(x -> x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Alvin"))
   .findFirst().get();
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
```

How to solve the error?

Actually, I just expect it should return one object or `null`.

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace of the exception that is thrown. In any case, you'll need to look at the options that [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) offers you (e.g. [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)))

Comment: Exception
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present

Comment: don't "expect", but read the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`get` will throw an exception if called on an empty `Optional`. Instead, you could use [`orElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) to return a `null`:

```java
Person b2cInwardAllocTxs = 
    personList.stream()
              .filter(x -> x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Alvin"))
              .findFirst()
              .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `Optional.get` throws `NoSuchElementException` is there is no such element. `orElse` allows getting with a default substituted is there is not an element.

```
Person b2cInwardAllocTxs =  personList.stream()
   .filter(x -> x.getName()
   .equalsIgnoreCase("Alvin")).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 3):

To solve your problem, you can use `.orElse(null)`.

It will return the value if present, otherwise return `null`

```
Person b2cInwardAllocTxs = personList.stream()
   .filter(x -> "Alvin".equalsIgnoreCase(x.getName()))
   .findFirst()
   .orElse(null);
```